# How can I reset my Xbox 360 wireless headset?

Tags: xbox-360

I've been using my wireless headset for sometime now. My wireless controller was damaged and now have a new one. I connect the controller to the console perfectly as user 1, but my wireless headset won't connect to user 1. It'll connect to users 2, 3, and 4, but wont allow me to connect as user 1 with the new controller.

How can I reset the headset to acknowledge the new wireless controller?

Answer (score 5):

I'll assume you have one of the generic wireless headsets that come in many skins, but are all based on the Microsoft design.  I've had one or two of these, and I agree the interface for connecting them isn't so obvious.  Luckily, MS has a pretty good article on it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927346).

The key info is:

> If a controller is connected to the first quadrant, the system will associate your wireless headset with the first quadrant. If another wireless headset is already associated with the first quadrant, your wireless headset will be associated with the second quadrant.
>   If you want to associate your wireless headset with a controller on a different quadrant, press the connect button on the wireless headset. This manually advances the quadrant to match the quadrant of the controller that you want.
>
> For example, to associate your wireless headset with a controller that is connected to quadrant 3, press the connect button three times within 20 seconds of when you started the connection process. You will hear one beep from the wireless headset if you select the first quadrant, two beeps if you select the second quadrant, and three beeps if you select the third quadrant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I looked it up with xbox and it may be that you have a defected controller, contact them for more help. If you still can't get the controller and headset to work together at least you may be able to get another controller from them.

Answer (score 0):

Hi! I had this problem when I got a new wireless headset. I found some info from a guy who worked in the industry who said the controllers mike jack might be the reason: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091206181005AA97Nly. As in it was worn and the controller thought it had a wired jack still in. So I undid the screws and fiddled with the jack receiving unit on the PCB. I got the wired jack, inserted it and flexed it a little. Finally after 36 hrs of grief the darned thing went to quadrant 1 and I have comms. Yay for me. I hope this helps.